# Combined sentences, "not ..., either ... or ..." v.s. "not ..., neither ... nor ..."

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, conditionals

Generally, given that there are two statements are true:

- A is not O in X.
- A is not O in Y.

> Question: To combine the two sentences into one, should one say which of the following (?):
>
> - A is not O, either in X or in Y.
>
> or
>
> - A is not O, neither in X nor in Y.
> - A is not O, both in X and in Y.
>
> What does each sentence mean? Could some of them mean the same?

e.g. To be more specific, A can be an Apple, O can be an Orange.

- An Apple is not an Orange in the X city.
- An Apple is not an Orange in the Y city.
- An Apple is not an Orange, either in the X city or in the Y city.
- An Apple is not an Orange, neither in the X city nor in the Y city.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English

Comment: There are many related previous questions (which are not closed). But mine is different.

Answer (score 1):

"A is not O, either in X or in Y." implies that X and Y are the only two options. If there is some Z for which A might be O, it would better to say "In both X and Y, A is not O." You can also say "A is O in neither X nor Y".

Comment: Thanks, +1, how about this one: "A is not O, neither in X nor in Y" ?